# How can I improve processing time with threads on Spyder?

Tags: python, multithreading, spyder

I'm trying to change the date format of a column in a CSV. I know there are easier ways to do this, but the goal here is to get the threads working properly. I work with Spyder and Python 3.8.
My code works as follows:

- I create a thread class with a function to change the date format
- I split my dataframe in several dataframes according to the number of threads
- I assign to each thread a part of the dataframe
- each thread changes the date formats in its dataframe
- at the end, I concatenate all the dataframes into one

"serie" is my original dataframe.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import threading
import time

from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
from time import process_time

serie=pd.read_csv('XXX.csv')

in_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
out_format = "%Y-%m-%d"

class MonThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, num_thread):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.num_thread = num_thread
    
    #Thread function
    def run(self):
        for self.i in range(dataframes[self.num_thread].index[0], dataframes[self.num_thread].index[0] + dataframes[self.num_thread].shape[0]):
            date_formatee = datetime.strptime(dataframes[self.num_thread].loc[self.i, 'Date'], in_format).strftime(out_format)
            dataframes[self.num_thread].loc[self.i, 'Date'] = date_formatee

nb_thread = 80
dataframes = []

#Df divided in several
for j in range(nb_thread):
    a = j * (serie.shape[0] // nb_thread)
    if j != nb_thread - 1 :
        b = (j + 1) * (serie.shape[0] // nb_thread)
        df = serie.iloc[a:b,:]
    else: 
        df = serie.iloc[a:,:]
        b = serie.shape[0]
    dataframes.append(df)
    print("Intervalle", j, ": [", a, ",", b, "]")

tps1 = process_time()
print(tps1)

threads = []
for n in range(nb_thread):
    t = MonThread(n)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
    
dataframe_finale = pd.concat(dataframes)

print("\n\n\n")
tps2 = process_time()
print(tps2)
print("temps d'éxécution : ")
print(tps2 - tps1)
```

It's working, but I find the execution time quite long, for a total of 100000 values it takes me about 1min30 to process with no threads, but with 80 threads it takes me about 30 seconds, and with 200 or 400 threads I stagnate at 30 seconds. Is my code bad or am I limited by something?

Comment: Not to be rude, but yes, your code is bad. (a) If you don't have 80 cores, then running 80 threads will just reduce performance. (b) In general, if you find yourself `for`ing over something in a Pandas dataframe, you're doing something wrong. (c) Since you most of the work in Python code, the threads will be mostly waiting for the GIL.

Comment: Ok but here I don't do multiprocessing, with threads I can have many than the number of cores, why I see topics or posts where people speak about programs with 500 threads? If you are talking about multiprocessing then I agree that I am limited by the number of cores, but if not you should explain me, I'm not trying to do multriprocess (maybe I should). I know that "for" loop is clearly not the best but I dont know what to use instead, any loop will be bad right ?

Comment: Ok I can change the loop by the function you gave me below

Comment: Yes, you can have much more threads than you have cores, but if all of those threads are working 100% of the time in a busy loop, competing for a CPU core to run on, then there's no point. Programs with 500 threads are likely to have most of those threads waiting for something to happen.

Comment: Multiprocessing won't help you here either, since then you'll start "paying" for serialization/deserialization/mutating-the-dataframe-in-the-parent-process-after-results-come-in much more than the benefit of parallelization would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just letting Pandas do the work over the series?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('XXX.csv')

in_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
out_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format=in_format).dt.strftime(out_format)
```

On my Macbook, this processes a million entries in 5 seconds.

Another way to do the same (without date validation, though), is

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace(r"(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)", r"\3-\2-\1", regex=True)
```

which finishes the job in about 3.3 seconds.

Comment: The goal is that I manage to make a program that works with threads. I start from a simple program that yes I could solve in 3 lines but it's not what I'm looking for, I'm looking to do the same thing as efficient but with threads (or multiprocess but for the moment I haven't looked at multiprocess) to understand how threads work, I'm taking it as an exercise.

Comment: Well, you really can't do it efficiently with threads and loops in Python, that's the thing.

Comment: Ok, so I guess this is a bad exercise to learn threads, thank you